# google geocoding address breakdown

Tags: javascript, html, geocoding

I am very new to this and would like to know how to get the full string and not the first character as it is currently doing,

currently using the example of the html + js from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

```
function codeLatLng(callback) {
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
  var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);



    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      if (results[1]) {
        map.setZoom(17);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map



        });
       infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    document.getElementById('Addressb').value= results[0].formatted_address; //working
    document.getElementById('Strn').value = results[0].formatted_address[0];
    document.getElementById('Strna').value = results[0].formatted_address[2];




      } else {
        alert('No results found');
     }
   } else {
      alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });

}



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



    </script>
```

the results needs to get stored  in the specified text fields as bellow

```
Street Number: <input id="Strn" type="text"><br>
    Street Name: <input id="Strna" type="text"><br>
    Suburb: <input id="Subu" type="text"><br>
    Town: <input id="Town" type="text"><br>
    Code: <input id="Code1" type="text"><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate through the address components and then the types, here is the code

```
  var streetNumber;
  var streetName;
  var city;
  var state;
  var zip;
  var country;
  for(var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++){
    for(var k = 0; k < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; k++){
        if (results[0].address_components[i].types[k] == "street_number")
            streetNumber = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        else if (results[0].address_components[i].types[k] == "route")
            streetName = results[0].address_components[i].short_name;
        else if (results[0].address_components[i].types[k] == "locality")
            city = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        else if (results[0].address_components[i].types[k] == "administrative_area_level_1")
            state = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        else if (results[0].address_components[i].types[k] == "postal_code")
            zip = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        else if (results[0].address_components[i].types[k] == "country")
            country = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, code working fantastically and now i can concentrate on the styling and the rest of the site

Comment: Great, I am glad it is works for you, could you mark the question as Answered with this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingResponses) the Google Maps Geocoding docs, specifying the format of the response.

It looks like it does return the components of the address separately, in the `address_components` array, in a specific order.  So if you're geocoding a street address,  `address_components[0].long_name` should return the street address, `address_components[1].long_name` the street name, etc.

Hope that helps.